# Cypress with angular element detached of the DOM error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cypress

I am working with cypress to test an Angular application. Lot of tests failed because of an element is detached from the DOM error.
I have tried many solutions to fix this without using cy.wait(xxx).
I have tried:
`cy.get('element_selector').should('be.visible').click()` 
`cy.waitElementOption(selector, timeout, 'exist')` then click on the element 
`cy.get(selector).click({ force: true })`
or using https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events library.

None of these solution works 100% of the time.

Am I missing something about working with Angular and Cypress? Is there any other solution do to such kind on interaction?

Comment: Detached from DOM usually occurs when an event causes the elements to be changed on the page and test assertions are still using the old copy, particularly in a list e.g `ng-for`. You should add the full test, and the Angular code would be useful as well.

Comment: Also show `cy.waitElementOption()` and how it relates to the problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try to extract some Angular code to illustrate my problem.